# If condition statment within function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have one question which is probably easy for a lot of you. I would like to write a function which will do the calculations based on condition in selected column. It will be easier to show you an example:

```
con <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "D", "A", "B", "D", "D", "D")
value <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2)
dat <- data.frame(con, value)
head(dat)
```

So one possibility would be to do this in this simple way:

```
dat$new <- ifelse(dat$con == "A", dat$value*10,
             ifelse(dat$con == "B", dat$value*100, dat$value*1000))
head(dat)
```

But, my question is how would the function look like? I tried something like this, but it is not working. Can someone help me with explanation what is missing and wrong?

```
calc <- function(dat) {
           if(dat[, con] == "A") {
           new <- dat$value*10 
           }  
           if(dat[, con] == "B") {
           new <- dat$value*100 
           } else {
           new <- dat$value*1000
         }
       }
calc(dat)
```

Comment: Why not use `ifelse`?

Comment: First error I see: `(` of the `if` conditions are not closed!

Comment: :) I corrected this, sorry

Comment: Second error I see: the first `{` it is not closed. Your last one refers to the else condition.

Comment: :) now I hope that all the brackets are closed

Comment: Yes now brackets look ok but the problem is another.  I bet the error message R gives to you is about length of condition.

Comment: no, the function gives no error masage, but when I try to use it with calc(dat) the error is undefined columns selected

Comment: They are undefined because they are not in quotes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
calc <- function(dat) {
  dat$new <- ifelse(dat[,'con'] == 'A', dat[,'value']*10,
         ifelse(dat[,'con'] == 'B', dat[,'value']*100,
                dat[,'value']*1000)
         )
  dat
}
```

The subsetting operator `$` is problematic in functions. Instead using the framework `DF[,'<variable>']` is better. Also, note the quotation marks around the variable names (column names). Also your original function does not print a result to the screen. The last command will be returned when the function is called.

```
calc(dat)
   con value  new
1    A     1   10
2    B     3  300
3    B     2  200
4    C     1 1000
5    C     1 1000
6    A     1   10
7    D     2 2000
8    A     1   10
9    B     2  200
10   D     3 3000
11   D     3 3000
12   D     2 2000
```

Comment: One more small think. How would this be done with if sentence and not ifelse?

Comment: It's tricky because `dat[,'con'] == 'A'` checks each value in the column one at a time. So it will produce a vector of T's and F's. Like `[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE...` But the if statement is waiting for one test of T or F. So the engine will just grab the first logical in the vector. `ifelse` is ready to accept many T's and F's by design. The two functions look similar, but they are built differently.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a function without `if` and `ifelse`:

```
calc <- function(data)
  transform(data, new = value * 1000 / 100 ^ (con == "A") / 10 ^ (con == "B"))
```

The function is based on mathematical operations.

```
calc(dat)
#    con value  new
# 1    A     1   10
# 2    B     3  300
# 3    B     2  200
# 4    C     1 1000
# 5    C     1 1000
# 6    A     1   10
# 7    D     2 2000
# 8    A     1   10
# 9    B     2  200
# 10   D     3 3000
# 11   D     3 3000
# 12   D     2 2000
```

Comment: Thank you. This function looks much simper!

Comment: @MtS You're welcome. The function should also be faster for large data sets.